# Theos: MPAVController tweak not working

Tags: objective-c, jailbreak, theos

I have tried many different times to make a tweak where a new UISlider is added to a video player view, which I assume is `MPAVController` with the `-(id)videoView` method. Here's my code:

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MPAVController.h>

id contentPlayer;
UISlider *slider;

%hook MPAVController

-(id)videoView{

    contentPlayer = %orig;

    slider = [[UISlider alloc] init];
    [slider setValue:[UIScreen mainScreen].brightness];
    slider.frame = CGRectMake(832.0, 50.0, 190.0, 32.0);
    [contentPlayer addSubview:slider];

    return contentPlayer;
}

%end
```

Any ideas how this code could be a problem? I'm pretty sure my `Makefile` is fine, along with `control`. I'm fairly new to this, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're having?

Comment: @AlexZielenski Nothing happens when I play a video.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the class you are hooking is not the one being used or its views might not be visible. You can try logging different classes that could lead you to the correct class and methods to hook. There's also a tool called cycript that can help you search, test and modify objects in runtime without having to compile any tweak.

Aside from that, the global variables are unnecessary as such (can be local variables to the method you're hooking), the slider is not released (unless you are using ARC) and the initialization could be done with `-initWithFrame:` like other UIKit initializations

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm VERY new to this, could you please explain how to log a class? thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: Hook a method and use %log; in it. Your original hook would be: `%hook MPAVController
-(id)videoView { %log; return %orig(); }
%end`

Comment: Here's what I got in my syslog: `Jul 29 16:32:48 Johns-iPhone Videos[2256]: -[<MPAVController: 0x15f820e0> videoView]
Jul 29 16:32:49: --- last message repeated 8 times ---` Does this mean it is the correct method, or not?

Comment: It does mean that that method is called 8 times in a row. If it is the method you are looking for, it can't be deduced from this data. Try modifying this object to see if it affects the view you are trying to add a slider to.

Comment: Actually I figured it out a few days ago. It was not the class I was looking for, I actually wanted MPVideoPlaybackOverlayView.